# IOS url scheme and facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to get around the documentation with no real success.

I defined a URL scheme for my app:

```
<myappname>://?param1=X&param2=Y
```

Now I want to include this address in posts (`presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction` or `presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession`)

Which URL do I need to provide in posting?

(when I give this URL I'm getting `API code 100 - link URL is not properly formatted`)

Just to clarify - when I put this address in Safari - everything works, I'm redirected to the right place in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only share http/https urls via the share dialog. If you want a link to your app, you should embed the :// scheme as an al:ios:url meta tag in an http url.